Avoid component execution on passing the same props
I am describing a simple scenario where I want the Todo component to be execued only once because same prop is passed . I have used the memo hook but it did not solve the problem .
import Todo from "./components/Todo";


function App() {
    return (<div>

        <h1>My Todos</h1>
        <Todo text="Learn React"/>
        <Todo text="Learn React"/>
        <Todo text="Learn React"/>
    </div>);
}

export default App;


import {memo} from "react";

const Todo= memo(function Todo({text}){
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <h2>{text}</h2>
        </div>
    );
})

 export default Todo;



What do you mean by execute once? In the App, if you call the Todo component 3 times, it will render 3 separate independent components.

Let me teach you memo , Note that the parent renders only once . If the parent re renders again because of state changes then memo will come into picture and will not call Todo component 3 times  . You can add additional button in the app and change a state in app when button is clicked  and then add console log statement in Todo to verify my statement . The question is that how to stop the Todo component calling three times when the parent component only renders once .

What do you mean by telling me about memo, when I see that you don't understand anything about how react works. Calling the Todo component in App 3 times will create 3 independent objects, when the App renders, the 3 Todos will render accordingly. Even if you set a button and change the state in App, it won't make the Todo component re-render because Todo already uses memo (because the input is a string, simply understand it as comparing values, so react doesn't see any change and doesn't make the component re-render). You should review the way you ask questions to others.

I dont feel the question is needed to be reviwed . Its pretty straightforward .  Avoid Todo component execution on passing the same props and it should only execute one time  . If you are very strong in React then stop arguing and give me the solution .

React treats each Todo component as unique instance because they are separate JSX elements. Even if the props are same, each instance is rendered independently, so React.memo will not optimize this scenario.
You can avoid rendering component multiple times by creating single instance and reusing it.
import Todo from "./components/Todo";

function App() {
    const todoElement = <Todo text="Learn React" />; // Create a single instance of Todo

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>My Todos</h1>
            {todoElement}
            {todoElement}
            {todoElement}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

Solution 2
import React, { memo, useMemo } from 'react';

// Optimized Todo component
const Todo = memo(function Todo({ text }) {
  console.log(`Rendering Todo: ${text}`); // For demonstration
  return (
    <div className="p-4 border rounded-lg shadow-sm mb-2">
      <h2 className="text-lg font-medium">{text}</h2>
    </div>
  );
});

// Main TodoList component
const TodoList = () => {
  // Sample todos with duplicates
  const todos = ["Learn React", "Learn React", "Learn React"];
  
  // Get unique todos with their counts
  const uniqueTodosWithCount = useMemo(() => {
    return todos.reduce((acc, todo) => {
      acc[todo] = (acc[todo] || 0) + 1;
      return acc;
    }, {});
  }, [todos]);

  return (
    <div className="p-6">
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">My Todos</h1>
      {Object.entries(uniqueTodosWithCount).map(([text, count]) => (
        <div key={text} className="flex items-center gap-2">
          <Todo text={text} />
          {count > 1 && (
            <span className="px-2 py-1 bg-gray-100 rounded-full text-sm">
              ×{count}
            </span>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoList;


Thats what I am trying to explain , take the dynamic lists . The Todo re - renders which should not happen . I hope you understand my requirement .

The key here is not doing anything and not able to solve the problem

I understand your issue - you want to prevent unnecessary re-renders of the Todo component when the same props are passed. While you're using memo, there are a couple of issues to address:
Using index as a key can cause unnecessary re-renders
The array contains duplicate values which React still sees as separate items


Instead of using the index as the key, we use the text itself. Since the text is the same for all items in the array, React will treat them as the same component and avoid re-rendering them unnecessarily.
 did not solve the problem

added solution 2 I hope it is what you want!

This feature is not existing in React . May be they will create a hook that will solve this particular problem in future .

thanks for helping me but the todos array for me looks like this              const todos = [ {text:"abcd",date:"11-11-2024"},{text:"abcd",date:"10-10-2024},{text:"lmn",date:"9-11-2024},{text:"lmn",date:"12-11-2024} ];
